# Git stopped working with authentication failures but ONLY on my mac?

Tags: git

We use microsoft AD.  For the past 6+ months I've been able to git clone, git pull, etc. on both my windows and mac machines.

This week my mac stopped working for git commands with an authentication error - even though I can still do stuff (git commands, clone, pull, etc.) on my windows machine - how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably had a git upgrade that knocked out my authentication configuration.

I was able to fix this by running the following command

```
git-credential-manager install
```